# CSS Performance, #id vs .class vs [^regex$] vs selector

Tags: css, performance, performance-testing

I have seen that it is a performance hit to do something like:

```
a[rel^=ext] {
```

Which makes sense.  But I have also found a bit of code in a template I used that does this for each section on the site:

```
@print {
 #section-name {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
 }
}
```

I figured I could just use `[^]` to select them all and making one rule and saving lines of code.  Then I found out that would be a performance hit.

So I checked and discovered that there is an outer div with an id.  So then I thought I could do `#idName section`.

But that uses an element, so again would probably be a performance hit I assume.

Does anyone have any information where I can find out more about performance and which way would be the quickest.  e.g. is the performance hit on a bigger file worse or the computation of many selectors worse?

As a further part, I find this sort of thing very interesting, does anyone have a good, reliable way to test these things?  Using online services gives a different result each time, so would require thousands of goes to make good numbers.  Does anyone know a good way to undertake these actions?

Comment: Just my two cents: You'll probably have a thousand factors in a full-blown website or web app that have a greater performance impact than your CSS selectors, so I wouldn't waste too much time on that decision. Regarding testing, modern in-browser dev tools come with a waterfall view that will show you which part of the page rendering process takes how long. But it's completely normal that you will have slightly differing values on each page load locally as well.

Comment: Understood, probably a fair point too.  Regarding testing I was thinking I need to automate 100 page loads and take an average because of the discrepancies in the various factors.  I found this so I'll give it a try: https://github.com/locustio/locust

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/optimizing-css-id-selectors-and-other-myths/ check that out

Comment: @disinfor please post an answer if you would like to be marked correct.  As you gave me the most proof.  Please copy and paste data to avoid broken links.  Here are some links I found useful.  https://benfrain.com/css-performance-revisited-selectors-bloat-expensive-styles/ https://codepen.io/Balloony/pen/vYYEbao even in 2014 the differences were minimal.  Firefox was fastest interestingly.  Not something to be worried about :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Eoin's request, I'm making an answer for future visitors (as I think this is useful).

From this link: https://www.sitepoint.com/optimizing-css-id-selectors-and-other-myths/

The following snippet runs on 50,000 nodes. The console output will give you an answer on performance for specific selectors.

```js
const createFragment = html =>
  document.createRange().createContextualFragment(html);

const btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
const container = document.querySelector(".box-container");
const count = 50000;
const selectors = [
  "div",
  ".box",
  ".box > .title",
  ".box .title",
  ".box ~ .box",
  ".box + .box",
  ".box:last-of-type",
  ".box:nth-of-type(2n - 1)",
  ".box:not(:last-of-type)",
  ".box:not(:empty):last-of-type .title",
  ".box:nth-last-child(n+6) ~ div",

];
let domString = "";

const box = count => `
<div class="box">
  <div class="title">${count}</div>
</div>`;

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log('-----\n');
  selectors.forEach(selector => {
    console.time(selector);
    document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    console.timeEnd(selector);
  });
});

for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  domString += box(i + 1);
}

container.append(createFragment(domString));
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn {
  background: #000;
  display: block;
  appearance: none;
  margin: 20px auto;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 24px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.box-container {
  background: #E0E0E0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 25%
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Measure</button>
<div class="box-container"></div>
```

From the sitepoint link as well, here is some more data with information to back it up:

> The test was bumped up a bit, to 50000 elements, and you can test it out yourself. I did an average of 10 runs on my 2014 MacBook Pro, and what I got was the following:
>
> - Selector :  Query Time (ms)
> - div : 4.8740
> - .box : 3.625
> - .box > .title : 4.4587
> - .box .title : 4.5161
> - .box ~ .box : 4.7082
> - .box + .box : 4.6611
> - .box:last-of-type : 3.944
> - .box:nth-of-type(2n - 1) : 16.8491
> - .box:not(:last-of-type) : 5.8947
> - .box:not(:empty):last-of-type .title : 8.0202
> - .box:nth-last-child(n+6) ~ div : 20.8710
>
> The results will of course vary depending on whether you use `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll`, and the number of matching nodes on the page, but `querySelectorAll` comes closer to the real use case of CSS, which is targeting all matching elements.
>
> Even in such an extreme case, with 50000 elements to match, and using some really insane selectors like the last one, we find that the slowest one is ~20ms, while the fastest is the simple class at ~3.5ms. Not really that much of a difference. In a realistic, more “tame” DOM, with around 1000–5000 nodes, you can expect those results to drop by a factor of 10, bringing them to sub-millisecond parsing speeds.

The takeaway from all this:

> What we can see from this test is that it’s not really worth it to worry over CSS selector performance. Just don’t overdo it with pseudo selectors and really long selectors.

Another test here: https://benfrain.com/css-performance-revisited-selectors-bloat-expensive-styles/ covered data-attribute and regex selectors.  It found:

> 1. Data attribute
> 2. Data attribute (qualified)
> 3. Data attribute (unqualified but with value)
> 4. Data attribute (qualified with value)
> 5. Multiple data attributes (qualified with values)
> 6. Solo pseudo selector (e.g. :after)
> 7. Combined classes (e.g. class1.class2)
> 8. Multiple classes
> 9. Multiple classes with child selector
> 10. Partial attribute matching (e.g. [class^=“wrap”])
> 11. nth-child selector
> 12. nth-child selector followed by another nth-child selector
> 13. Insanity selection (all selections qualified, every class used e.g.
>        div.wrapper > div.tagDiv > div.tagDiv.layer2 > ul.tagUL >
> 14. li.tagLi > b.tagB > a.TagA.link)
> 15. Slight insanity selection (e.g. .tagLi .tagB a.TagA.link)
> 16. Universal selector
> 17. Element single
> 18. Element double
> 19. Element treble
> 20. Element treble with pseudo
> 21. Single class

Here are the results.  You should note they are from 2014 browsers. All times in milliseconds:

```
Test    Chrome 34   Firefox 29  Opera 19    IE9     Android 4
1       56.8        125.4       63.6        152.6   1455.2
2       55.4        128.4       61.4        141     1404.6
3       55          125.6       61.8        152.4   1363.4
4       54.8        129         63.2        147.4   1421.2
5       55.4        124.4       63.2        147.4   1411.2
6       60.6        138         58.4        162     1500.4
7       51.2        126.6       56.8        147.8   1453.8
8       48.8        127.4       56.2        150.2   1398.8
9       48.8        127.4       55.8        154.6   1348.4
10      52.2        129.4       58          172     1420.2
11      49          127.4       56.6        148.4   1352
12      50.6        127.2       58.4        146.2   1377.6
13      64.6        129.2       72.4        152.8   1461.2
14      50.2        129.8       54.8        154.6   1381.2
15      50          126.2       56.8        154.8   1351.6
16      49.2        127.6       56          149.2   1379.2
17      50.4        132.4       55          157.6   1386
18      49.2        128.8       58.6        154.2   1380.6
19      48.6        132.4       54.8        148.4   1349.6
20      50.4        128         55          149.8   1393.8
Biggest Diff.   
        16          13.6        17.6        31      152
Slowest         
        13          6           13          10      6
```